# ¿estaria correcto el codigo en MVC? con java usando eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, eclipse, jpa

```
private boolean cargaDatos(Estudiante est, HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean ok = true;
    String idi = request.getParameter("txtId");
    String apell = request.getParameter("txtApellido");
    String nom = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
    String recibida = request.getParameter("txtFechaIn");
    
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date fecha = new Date();
    try {
        fecha = formato.parse(recibida);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return ok;
    
}
```

en el tipo fecha donde mi mysql tengo un dato de fecha tipo date? seria la correcta la solucion que describo? se agradece la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de parse, yo utilizo el método format siempre que la fecha ya te venga como fecha. O sea, si la fecha es un string, entonces si utilizaríamos el método parse para convertir el string en una fecha.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //generamos la fecha, tu la recibes en una variable
    Date fecha = new Date();
    //en un string guardamos el formato deseado
    String formato = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    //pasamos ese formato al método SimpleDateFormat
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
    //usamos ese formato pasándole nuestra fecha para formatearlo
    System.out.println(formatoFecha.format(fecha));
}
```

Aunque bueno, para la fecha, depende de lo que deseas, por lo de poner antes o después del año:

"dd-MM-yyyy"

Para convertir una cadena de texto en un obejto LocalDate (Solo almacena fechas y no tiempo) puedes usar el método parse de la siguiene manera:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2018-09-16");
```

O directamente:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 09, 16);
```

Comment: seria lo mismo ?

Comment: Edité la respuesta, a ver si ahora lo expliqué algo mejor. Si la fecha la recibes como string, entonces utilizamos el método parse para convertirla en una fecha y con el método SimpleDateFormat para formatear la fecha

Comment: si gracias ahora un poco mejor lo entendi gracias